Quotient map from $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$ to $\mathbb{S}^2$ is not nullhomotopic
I'm trying to prove that the map $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$ collapsing $\mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^1$ induces an isomorphism between $H_2(\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1)$ and $H_2(\mathbb{S}^2)$ (hence it's not nullhomotopic). I guess I'm supposed to consider the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow H_2(\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1) \rightarrow H_2(\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1, \mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^1) \xrightarrow {\delta} H_1(\mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^1) \xrightarrow{i} H_1(\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1) \rightarrow \cdots$. This way, the first map sure is injective and I'd like to prove it's surjective too. Hence I need to prove that $\delta$ is $0$, which I can do either directly or by showing that $i$ is injective. However I can't understand how to do any of this two. Any help?

Are the $H^n$ here homology or cohomology? Homology is usually written with subscripts $H_n$, and the long exact sequence you wrote is in homology I believe.
If this is homology, do you know that $\pi_1 (T^2)=H_1 (T^2) = \mathbb{Z}^2$? since $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$ is homeomorphic to $T^2$, there are explicit two generators of $H_1 (\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1)$ that you can find preimages for in $H_1 (\mathbb{S}^1 \wedge \mathbb{S}^1)$ thus proving that $i$ is injective.

What do you think? Do you know what the generators on first homology of $S^1\times S^1$ are?

@Bennie thanks, yeah I meant homology but wrote this in a rush, I'm editing the post right after this comment. If I'm correct, I can consider generators $a$ and $b$ for $H_1(T^2)$ obtained from the $\Delta$-complex structure of the torus. These are also generators for the $H^1$ of the $1$-skeleton of this structure, which is exactly $S^1 \vee S^1$. Hence $i$ is actually an isomorphism (sends generators to generators), and the rest follows. Does this make sense?

Here's two ways to show that $i_*\colon H_1(S^1 \vee S^1) \to H_1(S^1 \times S^1)$ is injective (in fact, an isomorphism):

Note that $i\colon S^1 \vee S^1 \hookrightarrow S^1 \times S^1$ is the inclusion of the 1-skeleton, where $S^1 \times S^1$ is equipped with the product CW-structure. We thus get a chain map
$\require{AMScd}\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
\begin{CD}
    0 @>>> 0  @>>> \Z^2 @>0>> \Z @>>> 0 \\
    @VVV @VVV @Vi_*V\cong V @VVV @VVV \\
    0 @>>> \Z @>>\partial_2 = 0 > \Z^2 @>>0> \Z @>>> 0
\end{CD}
between the cellular chain complexes for $S^1 \vee S^1$ at the top and $S^1 \times S^1$ at the bottom, and since all possible differentials are trivial the claim follows by taking homology.

If you don't want to use cellular arguments, you could also argue via the fundamental group: Pick generators $[\alpha], [\beta] \in \pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1) \cong \Z * \Z$. Then $i_* [\alpha], i_* [\beta]$ together generate $\pi_1(S^1 \times S^1) \cong \langle i_* [\alpha], i_* [\beta] \mid [i_* [\alpha], i_* [\beta]] = 1\rangle \cong \Z^2$ (if this is unfamiliar, try showing this yourself using van Kampen's theorem and a presentation of $S^1 \times S^1$ as the quotient of a square). In other words, $i_*\colon \Z * \Z \cong \pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1) \to \pi_1(S^1 \times S^1) \cong \Z^2$ is precisely the quotient map $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1) \to \pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1)^{\mathrm{ab}}$ and therefore induces an isomorphism on $H_1({{-}})$ by the Hurewicz theorem.



while I'm familiar with your second argument, can't you work directly at the level of homology by considering the $\Delta$-complex structure of the torus and that of a subcomplex for the wedge?

@Paz You could, yes. That would yield something similar to my first argument.

thank you very much for the double argument, I'll think about them properly.
